# Aiogram 2. Как игнорировать команды из чата? Бот должен реагировать только на команды в ЛС

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Мне нужно чтобы бот не реагировал на команды /start /help ну и вообще все которые отправляют в чат. Мне нужно чтобы бот реагировал только на команды в ЛС, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Не вовремя конечно, но вот что можно сделать

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["command"])
async def command(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == message.chat.id:
        await message.answer(message.from_user.id, "Hello")
```

Не лучшее решение конечно

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

**aiogram ^2.0.0**

*Вариант 1 - использовать проверку в каждой функции*

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def on_start(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == message.chat.id:
        await message.answer(message.from_user.id, "Hello")
```

*Вариант 2 - написать фильтр*

> не пользуюсь 2 версией и вам не советую, поэтому не смогу написать
> фильтр в слепую

**aiogram ^3.0.0**

*Добавьте в модуль, где у вас будут команды только для личного чата, данный фильтр:*

```
router = Router()
router.message.filter(
    F.chat.type == "private"
)
router.include_router(start.router)
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вот так

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def welcome(message: types.Message):
       await message.answer(message.from_user.id, "тест")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]